# git push heroku master hangs in the middle of the push

Tags: git, heroku

When pushing to Heroku (`git push heroku master`), my git client stops producing output after about 20 seconds. It usually hangs while processing the Gemfile. The pushes always work - I just stop getting output.

If it helps, here is the output i get from `ssh -v git@heroku.com`
https://gist.github.com/4496219

Comment: I think this was an issue on Heroku's end. My pushes suddenly started completing properly. I never solved this otherwise.

Answer (score 16):

I was having this issue and resolved it by running `heroku login` and logging in again.

Comment: It seems heroku has implemented some sort of auto-logout recently that is causing this issue. `heroku login` solved it for me

Comment: me too, I had changed pw few days back!

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue, though my pushes never went through - the deploy just hanged and nothing happened. It turned out to be a problem on Heroku side - on the [Heroku Status](https://status.heroku.com/) page they had posted that they are having issues with builds failing (which they fixed shortly).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a problem with Bundler. It's not reproducible locally because you have a cache with some gems. See http://artsy.github.com/blog/2013/01/15/debugging-bundler-issues-with-heroku, you want to follow instructions in https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me and someone told me to to a git pull origin master, then retry the git push heroku master. That worked. Still don't know why it hung in the first place, though.

Answer (score 0):

try `git pull origin master`
followed by `git push heroku master`